# Running "sudo composer" won't work after installing properly

Tags: php, bash, macos, composer-php, sudo

I have been trying to install composer on my Mac (running macOS Sierra). The composer.phar file is now located in `/usr/local/bin/composer/` and it works properly when I'm **not** running composer as a root.

```
$ composer -V
Composer version 1.2.4 2016-12-06 22:00:51
```

However, when I try to run composer as a root (which of course is required to install dependencies), I get this:

```
$ sudo composer
sudo: composer: command not found
```

I have no single clue how to fix it, has anyone else had this?

Comment: `sudo $( which composer )` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it must be a composer.phar renamed to composer into /usr/local/bin/ , not a directory composer/

From : https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

**Globally#**

You can place the Composer PHAR anywhere you wish. If you put it in a directory that is part of your PATH, you can access it globally. On unixy systems you can even make it executable and invoke it without directly using the php interpreter.

After running the installer following the Download page instructions you can run this to move composer.phar to a directory that is in your path:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

*Note:* If the above fails due to permissions, you may need to run it again with sudo.

*Note:* On some versions of OSX the */usr directory* does not exist by default. If you receive the error "*/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory*" then you must create the directory manually before proceeding:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

*Note:* For information on changing your PATH, please read the Wikipedia article and/or use Google.
Now just run composer in order to run Composer instead of php composer.phar.